# How to get JSON object using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to read this JSON using Retrofit but I got this error `Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class org.json.JSONObject.`

**The JSON in ALE2 file**

```
{
   "a1":[...],
   "a2":[...],
   "a3":[...]
}
```

**Code**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL).build();
retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class).getData().enqueue(new Callback < JSONObject > () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call < JSONObject > call, Response < JSONObject > response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call < JSONObject > call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

**RetrofitInterface**

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("ALE2")
    Call<JSONObject> getData();

}
```

I don't want to store them in any model I just want to get the JSON as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface should look like this :

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
    @GET("ALE2")
    Call<ResponseBody> getData();
}
```

To get raw json object return type should be `Call<ResponseBody>`
Once that is done in response you can handle it like below :

```
retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class).getData().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            String responseBody = response.body().string();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

This is how you can set string in JSON object.

Comment: It's working thank you